# Does the code in a C++ winsock 2 application have to change when using a global IP address?

Tags: c++, winsock2

My code is based on the book "Network Programming for Microsoft Windows Second Edition", which can be found online as a PDF.

My code for the server application is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>

int main(void)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ReceivingSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN ReceiverAddr;
    int Port = 5150;
    char buffer;
    SOCKADDR_IN SenderAddr;
    int SenderAddrSize = sizeof(SenderAddr);

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

    ReceivingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    ReceiverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ReceiverAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);
    ReceiverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    bind(ReceivingSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&ReceiverAddr, sizeof(ReceiverAddr));

    recvfrom(ReceivingSocket, &buffer, 1, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&SenderAddr, &SenderAddrSize);
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    buffer = 'b';
    sendto(ReceivingSocket, &buffer, 1, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&SenderAddr, SenderAddrSize);
    std::cin.get();
    closesocket(ReceivingSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

And for the client application is:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET SendingSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN ReceiverAddr;
    SOCKADDR_IN ex;
    int Port = 5150;
    char buffer = 'a';

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

    SendingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    ReceiverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ReceiverAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);
    ReceiverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("-->insert ip here<--");

    sendto(SendingSocket, &buffer, 1, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&ReceiverAddr, sizeof(ReceiverAddr));

    int len = sizeof (ex);
    recvfrom(SendingSocket, &buffer, 1, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&ex, &len);
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    closesocket(SendingSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

When I insert a local IP, the code works perfectly fine - the applications detect each other and exchange buffers.  But when I insert my global IP, the applications don't detect each other. Is it a problem with the code, or something I have to change when using a global IP, or something wrong with my network settings?

To clarify:

When I said about "inserting IP address", I meant writing it instead of `"-->insert ip here<--"`.

By local IP, I meant my computer's local IP address, checked in the console using the `ipconfig` command.

By global IP, I meant the global IP of my router, which I checked on `myglobalip.com`, and I forwarded port 5150 to my local IP address.

This might be a bit off topic, but if it's something wrong with network settings, I would appreciate if you could give a link to a good tutorial because I couldn't find one that worked.

Comment: What do you mean by "insert my global IP"? "Insert" how? "Insert" where? "Global" how and where? Please elaborate.

Comment: Does your client machine have multiple network adapters installed? If so, have you tried `bind()`ing the client's socket to the IP of the adapter that is physically connected to your router? There is no guarantee that a LAN machine sending traffic to the router's WAN (global) IP will trigger port forwarding to send the traffic back into the LAN. Typically the traffic has to actually come from the outside world that the WAN is connected to. Machines on the LAN that want to communicate with each other should be using each other's LAN IPs, not the router's WAN IP.

Comment: You may be running afoul of network address translation (NAT) in your router. Did you set up a DMZ or port forwarding to expose your local system to traffic coming in?

Answer (score 0):

Nice code.  Nice and simple.  All I had to do was cut and paste (and add `#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")`).

Are the client and the server both running on your LAN?  If so, my tests indicate that they won't be able to talk to each other via your router's external IP address.  This is because the router doesn't loop back packets sent out through its ADSL / VDSL port (why would it?) so they just disappear into the ether.  I tried enabling both the DMZ and port forwarding on my router (at minimum, you need one or the other) but no dice, which was what I was expecting.

So to test this, you will need the help of a friend with a router of his own.  Let's suppose he is running the client.  You will then need to put your server machine into your router's DMZ or (better, because it's safer) set up port forwarding for UDP port 5150 on your router to the server machine.  In either case, give that machine a static IP address on your LAN else it might move.  Then you have a chance of seeing this work.

Our friends over at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/456812/nat-and-udp-replies) have this to say about sending UDP packets via [routers implementing] NAT (which is what you will have there) *and getting an answer back*:

> IF Machine A sends [a UDP] frame from the same source port as the destination port ("Port N"), and IF the NAT is able to preserve that source port (i.e. it's configured to preserve source ports when possible, and that source port is not in use), THEN you can expect a reply to "Port N" to get back to Machine A.

But the problem currently is that nothing is listening.  Certainly not your server program.